# Trouble submitting AJAX form using hyperlink instead of submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having problem submitting a HTML form using JavaScript & AJAX from a hyperlink (href) instead of the normal input type. My current code is as follows:

**Javascript (executed just before body tag):**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //Chronicle Form 1
        $('#fm_chronicledate').submit(function(event) {
            var data = $('#fm_chronicledate').serialize() + 'cron=1' + '&chron_date=' + chron_date.val() + '&chron_time=' + chron_time.val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "script.php",
                    data: data, 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        if(html == 1){
                        $('#chron_part1').fadeOut('slow');
                        } else alert('Error');
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="fm_chronicledate" method="POST" action="#" >
<input type="text" class="website" name="chron_time" id="chron_time" />
<input type="text" class="website" name="chron_date" id="chron_date" />
<a href="#" class="chron_submit1" id="chron_submit1" onclick="fm_chronicledate.submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Anyways for some reason it just does not execute the AJAX.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can not just reference an element by its id! That is a horrible outdated practice.

Comment: I agree with @epascarello, best to attach the click event in the javascript file. Regardless, open your web browser's console, are there any errors in there?

Comment: Without input type submit you did not use jQuery.submit() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use inline javascript, you can reference the link in the main script and capture the click event, like this...

**HTML:**

```
<form id="fm_chronicledate" method="POST" action="#" >
    <input type="text" class="website" name="chron_time" id="chron_time" />
    <input type="text" class="website" name="chron_date" id="chron_date" />
    <a href="#" class="chron_submit1" id="chron_submit1">Submit</a>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chron_submit1').on("click", function(event) {
        var data = $('#fm_chronicledate').serialize() +
            'cron=1' +
            '&chron_date=' + $("#chron_date").val() +
            '&chron_time=' + $("#chron_time").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "script.php",
            data: data, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                if (html == 1) {
                    $('#chron_part1').fadeOut('slow');
                }
                else
                    alert('Error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the same result, nothing happens when I click the link. I also checked for any errors in my browser's console, and I seem to get "Uncaught ReferenceError: chron_date is not defined" when i hit the link, if that helps?

Comment: I didn't notice that you weren't referencing the other values correctly.  I've modified the code and it should work now :)

Comment: Great that did the trick. I also had a stupid syntax error in my PHP. Once I fixed both things it worked perfectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
<a href="#" class="chron_submit1" id="chron_submit1" onclick="Javascript:GetAjax()">Submit</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
    function GetAjax() {
        var data = $('#fm_chronicledate').serialize() + 'cron=1' + '&chron_date=' + chron_date.val() + '&chron_time=' + chron_time.val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "script.php",
                data: data, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    if(html == 1){
                    $('#chron_part1').fadeOut('slow');
                    } else alert('Error');
                }
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the onclick from your link and change it to

```
<form id="fm_chronicledate" method="POST" action="#" >
<input type="text" class="website" name="chron_time" id="chron_time" />
<input type="text" class="website" name="chron_date" id="chron_date" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chron_submit1" id="chron_submit1">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Change you event to

> $('#chron_submit1').click(function(event) {

Also you have an error in when serializing the form. Must be

> var data = $('#fm_chronicledate').serialize() + 'cron=1' +
>   '&chron_date=' + $(chron_date).val() + '&chron_time=' +
>   $(chron_time).val();